# Get previous week number from php week number

Tags: php, date, time

I currently need to get the previous week from a variable that passes a php week number so if it is week 13 I will get week 12.

The problem I am facing is that if I just minus 1 from the original number if I am in week 1 it will return week 0 unless I create an if statement ie:

```
if($week==1)
{
    $prev_week=52;
    $prev_year=$year-1;
}
```

This is assuming that php counts the weeks from 1 and not 0. This seems a bit clumsy and I was thinking there may be a better way of doing this utilizing PHP's many date and time functions.

Comment: Depending on the notation used, you may even have week number 53. The standards for this differ per region, so what is week 1 in amerika may be week 53 in Europe. A year doesn't have exactly 52 weeks, so you may need a leap week once in a while. ;)

Comment: yes I could see this happening. I would prefer to work on a monthly basis but my client insists on weekly invoicing :(

Comment: As the week and year number are stored in a database I could do a quick db query to check if there is a week 53 I suppose and if not set it to 52

Comment: It is actually possible for a year to have 54 weeks (the year 2000 is an example of this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I could be over complicating the problem - basically I need to obtain results from the database that appear in the previous weeks from the selected week therefore if there is a possibility of 54 weeks in a year all I really need to do is:-

```
 if($week==1)
 {
    $year_minsued=$year-1;
    $week_minused=54;
 }
 else
 {
    $week_minused=$week-1;
    $year_minused=$year;
 }
```

My select statement can then read:

```
SELECT SUM(post_price), SUM(total_price) FROM
database_table
WHERE client_id='$account_no'
AND
   (year<='$year_minused' AND week<='$week_minused')
```

I have not tested this as yet but thinks it should do the job.

Comment: Sorry - you got me worried that there might be a flaw in this method albeit a bit clumsy - if there is a flaw I would have liked to have known :)

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$currentWeek = date( 'W' );

$today = strtotime( date( 'Y-m-d' ) ) - 7*24*60*60; // last week this day
// change 7 to 30 to see last year's week numer

$lastWeek = date( 'W', $today );

echo $currentWeek . '--' . $lastWeek;
```

Hope this helps.

**Update**

```
$lastWeekNumber = date( 'W', strtotime( 'last week' ) );
```

Comment: Thanks - this works well for getting the previous week from the current week although will it work for when the 'currentWeek' is several weeks back (if that makes sense). I will have a play :)

Comment: You can check by editing the second line....just subtract as many days(in terms of seconds) as you want and see if that works.

Comment: Best answer. Weeks are always 7 days, so you can just add or subtract the number of week from an absolute date and get the week number from that. Let PHP do the week number handling for you, although you chould check if your client uses the same numbering. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
$PreviousWeek = date("W",strtotime("-1 week"));
```

Answer (score 2):

HamZa's and web-nomad's answers helped me to go a bit further and make sure, I get the right year. Using `date ('Y')` can lead to unexpected behavior since it can happen, that week 1 belongs to the next or the previous year according to ISO-8601 (which is what is used in Europe). Instead use `date ('o')`. Otherwise it can happen that you jump from week 52 to week 1 of the previous year (because the start of the week is in the previous year according to `date ('Y')`.

```
$jahr = 2014; // jahr means year
$kw   = 52;   // kw contains week
```

Using `date ('Y')`returns:

```
previousWeek: 51-2014
currentWeek: 52-2014
nextWeek: 01-2014
```

Using `date ('o')`returns:

```
previousWeek: 51-2014
currentWeek: 52-2014
nextWeek: 01-2015
```

See all the code together, e. g. for building forward and backward-links:

```
$kwBack['kw'] = date ("W", strtotime ($jahr. 'W' . str_pad ($kw, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT). ' -1 week'));
$kwBack['jahr'] = date ("o", strtotime ($jahr. 'W' . str_pad ($kw, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT). ' -1 week'));

$kwNext['kw'] = date ("W", strtotime ($jahr. 'W' . str_pad ($kw, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT). ' +1 week'));
$kwNext['jahr'] = date ("o", strtotime ($jahr. 'W' . str_pad ($kw, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT). ' +1 week'));

echo "previousWeek:     " . $kwBack['kw'] . "-" . $kwBack['jahr'];
echo "<br>currentWeek:  " . $kw . "-" . $jahr;
echo "<br>nextWeek:     " . $kwNext['kw'] . "-" . $kwNext['jahr'];
echo "<br>";

// Build the links

$urlBack = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?" . http_build_query ($kwBack);
$urlNext = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?" . http_build_query ($kwNext);

echo "Previous week: ". $urlBack . "<br>";
echo "Next week: ". $urlNext;
```

Answer (score 1):

We know that a year can be between 52 or 53 weeks. So, I created here a function that receives the current week and the current year. If this is true, it is obvious that the previous week will be the last week of the previous year, so through the variable year that I gave to this function, I subtract 1 to have the value or the previous year and I try to know how many weeks this year has, in this case that will be the week before week 1 for example. Otherwise, I subtract 1 in the value of the current week to have the value of the previous week.

i hope i have helped

function PreviusWeekNumber($ActualWeek, $Year){

```
     if($ActualWeek === 1){
         
         $TransformYearIntolastYear = $Year -1;
            
            $date = new DateTime;
            $date->setISODate($TransformYearIntolastYear, 53);
            $Result =  ($date->format("W") === "53" ? 53 : 52);
         
     }else{
         
         $Result = $ActualWeek -1;
         
     }
     
     return $Result;
     
 }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
$year = 2013; // Retrieved from the DB
$week = 1;
$prev_week = date("W",strtotime($year. 'W'.str_pad($week, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT). ' -1 week'));
echo $prev_week; // returns 52
```

A demo which shows the year:

```
$year = 2013; // Retrieved from the DB
$week = 1;
$prev_week = date("W - Y",strtotime($year. 'W'.str_pad($week, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT). ' -1 week'));
echo $prev_week; // returns 52 - 2012
```